# New line in a string is not works with text file

Tags: c#, string, file, utf-8, system.io.file

I have a function to write a message to text file. But when passing a string with 'Environment.NewLine', it is not writes a new line to the text file. Instead it writes '\r\n'.
How to correct this? I have tried with '\n' instead of 'Environment.NewLine'. Still the new line is not coming.
The issue is happens only when passing a string with new line to the function. Like variable 'message'

```
string message= "First "+Environment.NewLine+" message.";
LogTheDetails(message);

      public static void LogTheDetails(String message)
                {
          string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\logs";       
          var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
             if (directory.Exists == false)
                        {
                            directory.Create();
                        }
        
                        string FilePath = path + "/" +  currentdate + ".txt";
                        if (!File.Exists(FilePath)) //FILE WRITING FIRST TIME
                        {
                            File.Create(FilePath).Dispose();
                            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
                            {
              tw.WriteLine("============================================================\n --Logs--");
                            }
                        }
                        else if (File.Exists(FilePath))//IF FILE ALREADY EXIST - APPEND LINES
                        {
                            string testString= "testString"+ Environment.NewLine+ "WithNewLine";
        File.AppendAllText(FilePath, "\n============================================================\n");
                            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, message);
                            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, testString);  
        File.AppendAllText(FilePath, "\n============================================================\n");
                        }
        }
```

Output

```
============================================================
--Logs--
============================================================
 First \r\n message.
testString
WithNewLine
============================================================
```

Expected Output:

```
 ============================================================
    --Logs--
    ============================================================
    First
    message.
    testString
    WithNewLine
    ============================================================
```

Comment: your question is not clear. In what conditions do you want to write `\n` as it is? and which line should write a new line for it? Also I cannot see any line where you are writing `First `

Comment: @viveknuna  string message= "First "+Environment.NewLine+" message.";

Comment: Where and how do you call the function? - Btw: Code is jhard to read as your formatting is so messy!

Comment: whenever Environment.NewLine comes, it should write in new line. Now the output shows with '/r/n'

Comment: @TaW please check my code now

Comment: Looks (somewhat) better and I see the same behaviour here. It looks fine in the debugger but not in the file. Maybe __mixing__ those linefeed variations is a bad idea..

Comment: @TaW  mixing those linefeed variations  ? can  resolve this?

Comment: Hm, atm I can't really reproduce anymore. Note that you are missing a line feed before the testmessage. But the newline is showing up fine here. I'm on win10.

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code gave the output you are looking for, I tried it in .net 5 console application.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
class Program
{
    static string message = "First " + Environment.NewLine + " message.";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LogTheDetails(message);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }



    public static void LogTheDetails(string message)
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\logs";
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (directory.Exists == false)
        {
            directory.Create();
        }

        string currentdate = "test";
        string FilePath = path + "/" + currentdate + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(FilePath)) //FILE WRITING FIRST TIME
        {
            File.Create(FilePath).Dispose();
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
            {
         
tw.WriteLine("========================================================\n 
--Logs--");       
      
            }
        }
        else if (File.Exists(FilePath))//IF FILE ALREADY EXIST - APPEND 
 LINES
        {
            string testString = Environment.NewLine + "testString" + 
Environment.NewLine + "WithNewLine";
            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, 
"\n============================================================\n");
            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, message);
            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, testString);
            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, 
"\n============================================================\n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it is same as my code right? it is giving \r\n when opens the text file

Comment: Yes, It's almost the same code, as I mentioned it worked fine for me. Please create a new console application and paste the code. Ensure to delete the file if its already present just to ensure to start from scratch. In your case it could be some compatibility issue.

Comment: How about including comments where you've actually changed something and why?